# suggest a link with such concepts implemented - java and mysql

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

i need to write a program in java that will connect to a mysql database and execute some sql queries and display the result. suggest me a link with similar implementation / discussion of such concepts for guidance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably the easiest would be to use the predefined Desktop Database Template included with NetBeans.

It's based on the Swing Application Framework.

Benefits:

- drag and drop GUI
- all the pre-wiring is done. I mean... it would be hard to make more simple.

There's a complete tutorial [here](http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/java/gui-db.html). And another one [there](http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/java/gui-db-custom.html).

Answer (score 1):

I would look here: http://dev.mysql.com/usingmysql/java/
you will need the connector jar from mysql.
And then a basic jdbc tutorial from sun here: http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/jdbc/index.html

---

Answer (score 0):

Investigate object-relational mapping (ORM) libraries such as Hibernate. They encapsulate the JDBC API in a way that simplifies coding.

Comment: While I think ORM is great in many instances, it may be overkill for what the user is looking for, especially if they are asking about guidance on connecting to a database.  I think jdbc is the place to start, and then if needed move onto other concepts such as ORM.

Answer (score 0):

First start with the [JDBC tutorial](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/jdbc/index.html) to learn the generic JDBC concepts. You can consult the [MySQL JDBC documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.4/en/connector-j.html) for more MySQL-specific details such as how to create a connection string and more JDBC code examples. As next step you can learn the [DAO pattern](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2008/07/dao-tutorial-data-layer.html) how to manage your JDBC code nicely. If you want to go more further, then you can take a look for [JPA](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/tutorial/doc/bnbpz.html).

Answer (score 0):

NetBeans is not my favourite IDE but I must admit they have really nice tutorials and screencasts, especially for beginners.

So, you could maybe start with [Connecting to a MySQL Database](http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/ide/mysql.html). Then, have a look at [Creating a Simple Web Application Using a MySQL Database](http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/web/mysql-webapp.html). If you are more into Swing, maybe you'll prefer [NetBeans Platform CRUD Application Tutorial](http://platform.netbeans.org/tutorials/nbm-crud.html).

Without more details on the technologies you want to use and the type of application you want to build, it's actually hard to provide more guidance.